# PostgreSQL - Cannot UPDATE pg_database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am not able to UPDATE table pg_database with user postgres. As you can see below, i am able to run the SQL query, however nothing changes.

```
postgres=# select datname, datdba, datistemplate, datallowconn from pg_database;
    datname     | datdba | datistemplate | datallowconn
----------------+--------+---------------+--------------
 postgres       |     10 | f             | t
 template1      |     10 | t             | t
 template0      |     10 | t             | f
 my_template_1  |     10 | f             | t
(4 rows)

postgres=# UPDATE pg_database set datistemplate=true, datallowconn=false where datname='my_template_1' ;
UPDATE 1
postgres=# select datname, datdba, datistemplate, datallowconn from pg_database;
    datname     | datdba | datistemplate | datallowconn
----------------+--------+---------------+--------------
 postgres       |     10 | f             | t
 template1      |     10 | t             | t
 template0      |     10 | t             | f
 my_template_1  |     10 | f             | t
(4 rows)

postgres=#
```

Comment: BTW your `update` statement looks funny a bit, using parenthesis it is equal to `UPDATE pg_database set datistemplate=(true and datallowconn=false) where datname='my_template_1' ;` So it is always `false` for `my_template_1` because `datallowconn` is `true`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't update `pg_database` to change a database (you shouldn't be updating system tables at all, although you *can* do it for some of them).

Use [`ALTER DATABASE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdatabase.html) instead:

```
alter database my_template_1
  with is_template true
       allow_connections false;
```